# wordpress plugin to upload file directly to amazon s3

Tags: wordpress

hello i am trying to do this

1. i need to integrate a wordpress plugin so that when user uploads any video to my wordpress site it directly uploads to amazon s3 and when i need to use that video it gives me the url or automatically redirect to amazon to load the video
2. when user enters a url then the file uploads to local server and then immediately uploaded to s3 and the file is removed form my server, it is because the amazons3 do not allow remote files to be uploaded directly

ok for all of this is there any plugin? i found some but they allow this form there own interfaces but i need to do is when ever file is uploaded it directly goes to s3 and no other operation is needed to do this

if no plugin then please any tutorial for how to do this will be helpfull

it should be fully integrated with my wordpress theme

regards

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will do the job http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tantan-s3/ for any uploads.

If you want to upload theme files to s3 you need to do that manually.

Comment: and how i can manually do this please give any reference for help

Answer (score 0):

There is this plugin here: http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-aws-s3-browser/6470423 chekcout the live demo, I think it does what you need:

Demo: http://www.awss3.redwanhilali.net/?page_id=5#

Answer (score -3):

this plugin can do the work for you perfectly.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/

Comment: Does this plugin really do what the question asked?